# Array keeps displaying wrong number of indexes and values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

When the user correctly guesses the random number, the message should display how many total guesses were made and what each guess was. I have created an array, but the array shows 2 for the number of tries and the random number for the values every time. I understand that in the arrray, the index equals the total number of guesses and the value at each index should be the guess made. I added the .push function in each if statement loop, but it's still not working. I cannot figure out why. Please help.

I made 4 guesses (14, 61, 63, 62) on this run, and the array is still wrong.

[image: 1]

```js
function do_guess() {
  let guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;
  let message = document.getElementById("message");

  const guesses = [];
  guesses.push(guess);

  if (guess == num) {
    guesses.push(guess);
    message.innerHTML = "You got it! It took you " + guesses.length + " tries and your guesses were " + guesses;
  } else if (guess > Math.ceil(input)) {
    message.innerHTML = "That number is not in range!";
  } else if (guess <= 0) {
    message.innerHTML = "That number is not in range!";
  } else if (guess < 1) {
    message.innerHTML = "That number is not in range!";
  } else if (guess < num) {
    guesses.push(guess);
    message.innerHTML = "Try a higher number.";
  } else if (guess > num) {
    guesses.push(guess);
    message.innerHTML = "Try a lower number.";

  } else if (guess !== Number) {
    message.innerHTML = "That is not a number!"
  }
}
```

Comment: Each time you call `do_guess()` you create a new, empty array. You should declare the array outside the function so it gets the values from all calls.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but there are a couple of minor problems with your implementation:

1. Declaring `guesses` within your `doGuess` function means it's a new array each time `doGuess` is invoked; you lose the guess history.
2. You're calling `guesses.push` twice: once at the start of the function and again within the conditions.

You can solve the first (bigger) problem by moving `const guesses = []` outside of the function body.

```js
const guesses = []; // <= move this outside the function

function do_guess() {
  let guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;
  let message = document.getElementById("message");
  // ...
}
```

And the second by either removing the initial push call or removing the additional `push` calls within the conditions, so you're not adding the guess twice:

```js
function do_guess() {
  let guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;
  let message = document.getElementById("message");

  const guesses = [];
  guesses.push(guess); // <== either remove this

  if (guess == num) {
    guesses.push(guess); // <= or remove this
    message.innerHTML = "You got it! It took you " + guesses.length + " tries and your guesses were " + guesses;
  }

  // ...

  } else if (guess > num) {
    guesses.push(guess); <= and this 
    message.innerHTML = "Try a lower number.";
  }
```

Comment: 1. For the first issue, do I place the guesses array before the doGuess function then?

Comment: For the second issue, how do I prevent calling guesses.push twice. I put guesses.push in the loop of each condition because I wanted each guess to be pushed into the array. Is this not the Correct way of doing so?

Comment: For the first issue, yes. Declare the array before the function. For the second issue, you're calling `push` at the start of the function, and then calling it again inside the condition. You should do one or the other, but not both. Doing it in both places means the guess is added to the array twice, which is why your output says 2 guesses.

Comment: Omg thank you so so so much!! I finally got it after struggling with this for hours.